# Performance for Dependency Injection - Web Api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have been developing an API with .NET Core 2 and I am putting together several learning about design patterns. Lately I've been feeling confused as to whether I'm actually applying the pattern correctly. The project is based on Controllers, Services, Repository and a management I created to handle errors.

The point is that everything revolves around dependency injection and whatever structure I create for the project I have to define it in the Startup file as Singleton. According to the code below, the DI statements are growing with every resource I create (what the code shows is just a part).

```
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaAssinaturasItensServiceError, SistemaAssinaturasItensServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaAssinaturasServiceError, SistemaAssinaturasServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCompraStatusServiceError, SistemaCompraStatusServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaDescontosTiposServiceError, SistemaDescontosTiposServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPeriodicidadeServiceError, SistemaPeriodicidadeServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPeriodosServiceError, SistemaPeriodosServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosPrecoServiceError, SistemaPlanosPrecoServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosServiceError, SistemaPlanosServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosVigenciaServiceError, SistemaPlanosVigenciaServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPrecificacaoServiceError, SistemaPrecificacaoServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaVigenciaServiceError, SistemaVigenciaServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ICustomerServiceError, CustomerServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IPaymentProfilesServiceError, PaymentProfilesServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IPlanServiceError, PlanServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISubscriptionServiceError, SubscriptionServiceError>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosVigenciaService, SistemaPlanosVigenciaService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPeriodosService, SistemaPeriodosService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaVigenciaService, SistemaVigenciaService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPeriodicidadeService, SistemaPeriodicidadeService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosPrecoService, SistemaPlanosPrecoService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IAssinaturaService, AssinaturaService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IContratoService, ContratoService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPrecificacaoService, SistemaPrecificacaoService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaDescontosTiposService, SistemaDescontosTiposService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCompraPlanosService, SistemaCompraPlanosService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCompraPlanosItensService, SistemaCompraPlanosItensService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCompraService, SistemaCompraService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCompraItensService, SistemaCompraItensService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosService, SistemaPlanosService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosItensService, SistemaPlanosItensService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaAssinaturasService, SistemaAssinaturas>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaAssinaturasItensService, SistemaAssinaturasItensService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCreditosLogService, SistemaCreditosLogService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaAssinaturaUsuariosService, SistemaAssinaturaUsuariosService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaItensService, SistemaItensService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCreditosService, SistemaCreditosService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ITClientesContratosService, TClientesContratosService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ITClientesContratosPermissoesService, TClientesContratosPermissoesService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosPermissoesService, SistemaPlanosPermissoesService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ITClientesContratosValoresService, TClientesContratosValoresService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ITClientesContratosFormasPagamentoService, TClientesContratosFormasPagamentoService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ITClientesContratosCronogramaPagamentoService, TClientesContratosCronogramaPagamentoService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IUsuariosPermissoesService, UsuariosPermissoesService>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosVigenciaRepository, SistemaPlanosVigenciaDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPeriodosRepository, SistemaPeriodosDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaVigenciaRepository, SistemaVigenciaDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaAssinaturasRepository, SistemaAssinaturasDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaAssinaturasItensRepository, SistemaAssinaturasItensDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaAssinaturaUsuariosRepository, SistemaAssinaturaUsuariosDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCompraItensRepository, SistemaCompraItensDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCreditosRepository, SistemaCreditosDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCompraPlanosItensRepository, SistemaCompraPlanosItensDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCompraPlanosRepository, SistemaCompraPlanosDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCompraRepository, SistemaCompraDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCreditosLogRepository, SistemaCreditosLogDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaCreditosRepository, SistemaCreditosDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaDescontosTiposRepository, SistemaDescontosTiposDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaItensRepository, SistemaItensDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPeriodicidadeRepository, SistemaPeriodicidadeDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPermissoesRepository, SistemaPermissoesDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosItensRepository, SistemaPlanosItensDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosPermissoesRepository, SistemaPlanosPermissoesDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosPrecoRepository, SistemaPlanosPrecoDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPlanosRepository, SistemaPlanosDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ISistemaPrecificacaoRepository, SistemaPrecificacaoDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ITClientesContratosCronogramaPagamentoRepository, TClientesContratosCronogramaPagamentoDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ITClientesContratosFormasPagamentoRepository, TClientesContratosFormasPagamentoDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ITClientesContratosPermissoesRepository, TClientesContratosPermissoesDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<ITClientesContratosRepository, TClientesContratosDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IClientesContratosValoresRepository, TClientesContratosValoresDapper>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IUsuariosPermissoesRepository, UsuariosPermissoesDapper>();
```

Do you have a pattern that says how to follow these statements?

NOTE: I feel that the API is a little slow compared to other projects that do not follow the same pattern, although I have a nice idea that adding references as singleton prevents classes being instantiated at all times

Comment: Instead of sharing image paste your code as text in your question. [You should provide minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well its also probably a little slow because all your registrations are scoped as Singleton...

Comment: @maccettura Yes, I chose singleton because of the need to not instantiate classes at all times. There is also the reason that I have an obligation to declare as singleton the dependent classes of another singleton class

Comment: OK, by "little slow" what exactly do you mean? Have you measured? If yes, how? And have you found a bottleneck?

Comment: @maccettura if anything, singleton will consume more memory. Why singleton will have to be any slower than transient? (not taking into account implementations of classes - that can really break stuff)

Comment: @trailmax it’s a web app which means there is potentially multiple requests coming in at once, if there are only a single instance of _every_ dependent service then multiple requests would not be optimized

Comment: @maccettura I don't understand what you mean by "multiple requests would not be optimized"? Deep down inside of DI there will be some sort of a dictionary that contains a reference to the class instance and all what DI will have to do is to look up that reference by a key (that is usually a type name).

Comment: @trailmax I know. But what if a GET request comes in at the same time as a POST. They both depend on the _same_ service. There is only one instance of that service so one request has exclusive use of that service at a time (since there can only ever be one instance of each service)

Comment: @maccettura This "request has exclusive use of that service at a time" is just not true. Unless service is implemented in thread-safe manner with locking. When multiple requests demand the same service, they are handed refrences to the same instance and no locking is happening. And then requests are free to do whatever they like with the instances. And if singleton's state changes, you get threading issues and race conditions.

Comment: @maccettura Well, I did not do any measurement that gives me any real reason for slowness, just the feeling while debugging the application compared to other applications. However, as you said, it may be the implementation of the classes themselves. We conclude then that usually the number of clarifications in the container can easily surpass 50 without causing bottlenecks?

Comment: @maccettura Also, great explanation about sharing singleton classes between requests, we just have to be careful that they are stateless

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the Singleton scope. Almost certainly in a WebApi project services should be registered as Transient, or Scoped. Almost never as Singleton. (There are exceptions of course). I can only see problems with using Singleton for everything. Least of all memory issues.